# How to add 2 Json Arrays into 1 call

Tags: json, flutter, dart

so in my json I have something like The boys clothing and the Girls clothing. I was trying to
put both together and maybe in the future add more, so I can access all with the same string.

> Example

```
{
    "result": true,
    "shop": {
        "BoysProducts": [
            {
                "id": "b001",
                "name": "Blue Tshirt",
        "price": 12.99
        }
                    ],
         "GirlsProducts": [
            {
                "id": "g001",
                "name": "Pink Tshirt",
        "price": 12.99
        }
                    ]
}
```

```
class ShopResponse {
  final List<Shop> item;
  final String error;

  ShopResponse(this.item, this.error);

  ShopResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
  : item =
    (json["shop"]["BoysProducts"] as List).map((i) => Shop.fromJson(i)).toList(),
  error = "";

  ShopResponse.withError(String errorValue)
  : item = List(),
    error = errorValue;
}
```

What's the best way to add the Girls too so I can access both with only 1.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so what I've done was

```
    (json["shop"]["BoysProducts"] + json["shop"]["GirlsProducts"] as List).map((i) => Shop.fromJson(i)).toList(),
```

and worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this, whole JSON result as one object

```
class ShopResponse {
  bool result;
  Shop shop;
  String error;

  ShopResponse({this.result, this.shop, this.error});

  ShopResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    result = json['result'];
    shop = json['shop'] != null ? new Shop.fromJson(json['shop']) : null;
    error = null;
  }

  ShopResponse.withError(String error) {
    result = false;
    shop = null;
    error = error;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['result'] = this.result;
    if (this.shop != null) {
      data['shop'] = this.shop.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Shop {
  List<BoysProducts> boysProducts;
  List<GirlsProducts> girlsProducts;

  Shop({this.boysProducts, this.girlsProducts});

  Shop.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json['BoysProducts'] != null) {
      boysProducts = new List<BoysProducts>();
      json['BoysProducts'].forEach((v) {
        boysProducts.add(new BoysProducts.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    if (json['GirlsProducts'] != null) {
      girlsProducts = new List<GirlsProducts>();
      json['GirlsProducts'].forEach((v) {
        girlsProducts.add(new GirlsProducts.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.boysProducts != null) {
      data['BoysProducts'] = this.boysProducts.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    if (this.girlsProducts != null) {
      data['GirlsProducts'] =
          this.girlsProducts.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class BoysProducts {
  String id;
  String name;
  double price;

  BoysProducts({this.id, this.name, this.price});

  BoysProducts.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    name = json['name'];
    price = json['price'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['name'] = this.name;
    data['price'] = this.price;
    return data;
  }
}


class GirlsProducts {
  String id;
  String name;
  double price;

  GirlsProducts({this.id, this.name, this.price});

  GirlsProducts.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    name = json['name'];
    price = json['price'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['name'] = this.name;
    data['price'] = this.price;
    return data;
  }
}
```